# Two divs floated left next to each other the second must take up the rest of the line

Tags: html, css

HI, can someone please help me with this. I have:

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="width=100%">
    <div style="float:left; background-color:Red; height:100px">Red</div>
    <div style="background-color:Green;">Green</div>
    <div style="background-color:Yellow;">Yellow</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Which gives me exactly what I want, a Red div on the left with a Green div beside it taking up the rest of the width with a Yellow div beside the Red but below the Green div.

However the parent div actually has to also float left ie.

```
<html>
    <body>
         <div style="width=100%; float:left">
              <div style="float:left; background-color:Red; height:100px">Red</div>
              <div style="background-color:Green;">Green</div>
              <div style="background-color:Yellow;">Yellow</div>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This breaks it. Is there a way to get it working again with the parent div float left?

Comment: So, pretty sure my answer fixes it. Can you give some feedback if it doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

if you float the parent div, in order to keep them all in the parent container, you must also float them all. Those inside without float will fall out.

Edit: Note though that once you float them, width:100% means nothing anymore since the element don't know what to align 100% width with. Might have to give it some fixed width, or use JQuery to get width from document.

http://jsfiddle.net/robx/cpFUV/

Answer (score 1):

It breaks it because a `div` is normally set to have a width of 100% it's parent container. Setting `float:left` makes the width set to the content's width. Set a width on your parent container and it should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote `width=100%` instead of `width:100%` - fixed example:

```
<html>
    <body>
         <div style="float:left;width:100%;">
              <div style="float:left; background-color:Red; height:100px;">Red</div>
              <div style="background-color:Green;">Green</div>
              <div style="background-color:Yellow;">Yellow</div>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The reason it worked originally, is that there is an implicit width of 100% on block elements, but you made your `div` an inline element (of sorts) by adding the `float` (such that the width of the `div` reverted back to the content's width, just as your Red `div` works).

Your `width=100%` was always ignored, so by putting the `width:100%` as it should be, you are specifying a width for the element and all is well.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/hwb4w/